# SASS 'Invalid css error' when using variable from imported module

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, node-sass

I'm really new to Sass and having problems when importing variables from partial stylesheets. I thought it was pretty straightforward, but it seems not to be the case.

I'm using this stylesheet in a react component, importing like this:

```
import '../stylesheets/Table.scss';
```

The actual stylesheet (simplified, but with the same error) looks like this:

```
@use 'colors.scss';

.datatb-container {

    background-color: colors.$table-bg;
    border: 2px solid colors.$table-border;

    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 1.2%;
    max-width: 40rem;
}
```

And the file where my variables are located is called `_colors.scss`, in the same directory as `Table.scss`, and looks like this:

```
// App colors
$highlight: rgb(197, 145, 0);

// Table colors
$cell-bg: white;
$table-bg: gainsboro;

$cell-border: gray;
$table-border: black;
```

When I run React, I get the following error:

```
SassError: Invalid CSS after "...ound-color: color": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$table-bg;"
        on line 4 of ./src/stylesheets/Table.scss
>>     background-color: color.$table-bg;
```

I already tried changing directories, using the variables in different ways, changing the namespace with `@use 'colors' as {smth}`, but I always get the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@use` is not currently supported in node-sass (as of v4.14.1) and is only available in dart-sass

Comment: I finally found a github issue on this subject yesterday. Thank you for your answer. Do you know why it is not supported yet?

Comment: You can use the old `@import` until support is added

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE:
node-sass version 6.0 supports @use